# Extend PHP Class to allow new methods found via __callStatic

Tags: php, class, namespaces, extend

Looking for a flexible way to allow other developers to extend render methods for a templating system, basically allowing them to generate their own render::whatever([ 'params' ]) methods.

Current set-up work well from a single developer point of view, I have a number of classes set-up based on context ( post, media, taxonomy etc ), with a `__callStatic` method collecting the calling function which checks if the `method_exists` within the class, and if so, extracts any passed arguments and renders the output.

quick example ( pseudo-code ):

-- view/page.php

```
render::title('<div>{{ title }}</div>');
```

-- app/render.php

```
class render {

    public static function __callStatic( $function, $args ) {
         
        // check if method exists 
        if ( method_exists( __CLASS__, $function ){

            self::{ $function }( $args );

        }

    }

    public static function title( $args ) {
         
        // do something with the passed args...

    }

}
```

I want to allow developers to extend the available methods from their own included class - so they could create for example `render::date( $args );` and pass this to their logic to gather data, before rendering the results to the template.

The questions is, what approach would work best and be performant - errors are safety are not a big concern at this point, that can come later.

EDIT --

I am already making this work by doing the following ( pseudo-code again.. ):

-- app/render.php

```
class render {

    public static function __callStatic( $function, $args ) {
         
        // check if method exists 
        if ( 
            method_exists( __CLASS__, $function
        ){

            self::{ $function }( $args );

        }

        // check if method exists in extended class
        if ( 
            method_exists( __CLASS__.'_extend', $function 
        ){

            __CLASS__.'_extend'::{ $function }( $args );

        }

    }

    public static function title( $args ) {
         
        // do something with the passed args...

    }

}
```

-- child_app/render_extend.php

```
class render_extend {

    public static function date( $args = null ) {

        // do some dating..

    }

}
```

The issue here is that this is limited to one extension of the base render() class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way (used by Twig and Smarty, for a couple of examples), is to require developers to manually register their extensions as callables. The `render` class keeps a record of them, and then as well as checking its own internal methods, also checks this list from `_callStatic`.

Based on what you have already, this might look like this:

```
class render
{
    /** @var array */
    private static $extensions;
    
    public static function __callStatic($function, $args)
    {
        // check if method exists in class methods...
        if ( method_exists( __CLASS__, $function )) {
            self::{$function}(self::$args);
        }
        // and also in registry
        elseif (isset(self::$extensions[$function])) {
            (self::$extensions[$function])($args);
        }
    }
    
    public static function title($args)
    {
        // do something with the passed args...
    }
    
    public static function register(string $name, callable $callback)
    {
        self::$extensions[$name] = $callback;
    }
}
```

A developer would make use of this like so:

```
render::register('date', function($args) {
    // Do something to do with dates
});
```

Full demo here: https://3v4l.org/oOiN6

Comment: Thanks @iainn, I have already implemented this method, but I am hoping to find a simpler, more consistent route - I'll update my question to show one other route I am using now.

Comment: But, the idea is solid.. I'd just like the actual format of the render::method() to be consistent, so perhaps I will extract the registering to another function call and define the lookup point for these new methods..

Comment: Accepting the answer, as it pushed me down the right route - I'll add links to the solution on GH once this is all fleshed out. Basically I register any extension class and gather all methods, then run a check for extended_class::method -- thanks!